# rails not routing https

Tags: https, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

The following rails routes.rb file

```
  resources :aggregators, :constraints => { :protocol => "https"} do
    collection do
      get :confirm
      post :send_sms
    end
    member do
      post :confirmed
      post :failed
      post :cancelled
    end
  end
```

is not being called.  When a form calls one of these actions,

```
<%= form_for(@aggregator) do |f| %>
```

the user gets bounced to the root page of the application.  In comparing with and without the constraints, the non-https activity picks up

```
Started POST    [...]
Processing by AggregatorsController#create as HTML
```

whereas the https version

```
Started POST    [...]
Processing by AggregatorsController#index as HTML
```

So clearly the routing is missing the create action. (the bouncing back to home is an applicationController method which aplies a policy on the index action)  I assumed it would be an integral part of `resources`.  What am I doing wrong?  Better yet I only want to invoke https on specific actions and would like to keep the focus on new, create and confirm...